# In Moodle, is there a way to automate adding multiple quiz overrides for multiple students each taking multiple courses?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In our university, students with special needs are provided disability accommodations for graded quizzes, including term exams. Depending on the evaluation from academic affairs, a student could be granted a certain amount of extra time. It could be x1.5, x2.0, or even x3.0. The last one is the highest one I've seen so far.

Currently, we are doing this manually. We have to look up every student and manually add overrides to their quiz time limits for every graded quiz in every course that they are taking during the term. We do this at the start of every term.

Our problem is that this task is becoming unwieldy. At the start, it was fine with only very few students needing these accommodations. However, the student population is continuously growing and the number of students needing accommodations is, of course, growing as well. So, we are now more urgently needing a tool to automate this process.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but there is a group override

Quiz Administration > Group overrides

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Quiz_settings#Group_and_User_overrides

You'll probably have to add the users to a group first

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Groups

Comment: That will only work if we have all these students in the same course. However, the students could all be taking different courses, so having to add them to a group will only add another step.