# Set multiple auto attempt for Quiz based on condition on Moodle

Tags: moodle

I would like to set auto second/ third attempt for students who have got unsatisfactory mark (failed) in the first/ second attempt in a quiz on Moodle. Please share with me if you have any idea about setting up for this on Moodle.

This post might be related to my question but I have not able to find the right way to set up for my case.
[In Moodle, is there a way to automate adding multiple quiz overrides for multiple students each taking multiple courses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169802/in-moodle-is-there-a-way-to-automate-adding-multiple-quiz-overrides-for-multipl)

Thank you,
Thuy

[In Moodle, is there a way to automate adding multiple quiz overrides for multiple students each taking multiple courses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169802/in-moodle-is-there-a-way-to-automate-adding-multiple-quiz-overrides-for-multipl)